# Pass anchor's src attribute value to field of CF7

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have three links in main page

```
<a><img src="paris.jpg"></a>
<a><img src="london.jpg"></a>
<a><img src="NY.jpg"></a>
```

I have a text form CF7 with one text field

[text* city class:text placeholder "City"]

Form appears as popup when user clicks to any link.

MY TARGET

When i click to first image I want the word "London" to appear in field of the contact form. When i click to second - Paris, when i click third - NY. Then user can change information.

How could i do this? jQuery? JS? Please help.

Comment: Use buttons for action behaviors. [Anchors should only be used for navigation](https://css-tricks.com/use-button-element/#article-header-id-2).

Comment: Regarding your question... what have you tried? It's expected that you make an effort and ask about _specific_ problems you encounter.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to update your html and use jQuery (That's what I know).

First of all an a tag without a href attribute and title attribute is not valid html, it will work but screen readers and crawlers will have no idea what it is.
If you want to use the a tag as a trigger consider this format

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" title="YOUR TITLE HERE">
```

Now for what you need I would do something like this

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="popup-link" title="YOUR TITLE HERE" data-input-value="Paris">...</a>
```

Now that we have a link with a data attribute we can use it to populate the contact form 7 input, I see that the input has an ID of city (I would suggest adding a prefix to it, city is no generic and you could by accident target another element).

Now for the jQuery

```
jQuery('.popup-link').click(function(){
  jQuery('#city').val(jQuery(this).data('input-value'));
});
```

What we did here is target a click when user is clicking a link, then populating the city input.

hope this helps =].

Comment: Thanks. Should i add this code jQuery('.popup-link').click(function(){
  jQuery('#city').val(jQuery(this).data('input-value'));
}); to HEADER of page?

Comment: You will need to add this code after the jQuery is loaded, Without a jQuery file this will not work. Wordpress comes with a jQuery file already loaded. If you have a js that you enqueued you can pu it there. If not you can create one. If that is not possible you could add this script at the footer.php of your theme, just make sure to add it after wp_footer(), and don't forget to wrap the code in a script tag, and make sure that you don't insert the code inside a php tag

Comment: Anchors don't require `href` attributes for HTML5, and they shouldn't be used as buttons anyway. Use button elements instead.

Answer (score 0):

try this func, replace *#input* to id of your *form id* and add *class="toggle" data='Paris' (London,NY)* attributes to your images

```js
const form = document.querySelector('#input')
const toggle = document.querySelectorAll('.toggle');
for (let i = 0; i < toggle.length; i++) {
  toggle[i].onclick = function () {
    console.log(this.getAttribute('data'));
    form.setAttribute("value", this.getAttribute('data'));
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" />  

<a><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/miu-flat-social/60/stackoverflow-512.png" width="20px" class="toggle" data='Paris'></a>
<a><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/miu-flat-social/60/stackoverflow-512.png" width="20px" class="toggle" data='London'></a>
<a><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/miu-flat-social/60/stackoverflow-512.png" width="20px" class="toggle" data='NY'></a>
```

Comment: Thanks. Should i write your function in <script> or where?

Comment: in <script> </script> below form and input or in external JS file
no need JQERY lib, only plain JS

Comment: Your code is working but only when i am using standart <input>. When i use CF7 i have problems, not working. Have ideas?

Comment: what return console?

Comment: what in code your form input? class? id? `<input type="text" name="your-subject" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" aria-invalid="false">`

Comment: i understand. i should add "id" to input. There is only name was. Now everything is great. Thanks a lot!!!